# QGIS - Composer

Tags: qgis

My question concerns the general purpose of the composer in qgis. My first idea was that with the composer you can "save" different layer combinations with different style to gain the possibility the have different "views" on the same data. However I realized when I change the map in QGIS, the information in the composer is also refreshed. To clarify my intent I want to give a small example:
Assume you have the gas stations of different companies for a country and you want to produce a map with all companies and maps containing only the gas stations of a certain company. So in the beginning I though I just create different composers to gain different maps but I somehow fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can use the composer as you wish.
When you have finished a composer, click on the map and, in the object properties, just check "lock layers for this map." 
It should no longer be updated, even if you hide or display layers.
Regards.
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

For large projects with a large number of composers, it's better to use layer presets and the "Follow visibility preset" option within the composer.

This is because when using "lock layers" and "lock layer styles", it saves all of the layers and their styles and properties. When it does this for each composer, it can quickly balloon the size of the QGIS file. This can make it take an extremely long time to open a project, cause a lot of performance issues, and inevitably will corrupt your QGIS file. Following a visibility preset simply references the style for the layer rather than duplicates it.

E.g. I had an employee whose QGIS file got corrupted and I had him send it and the backup files to me. On review, the primary QGIS file was empty, and the backup file was an exceptional 65mb. The markup behind the QGIS file was nearly a million lines long. It was corrupted because it got cut off, so I'm not even sure how long it might have been in it's entirety. This was a result of him having about 30 layers and over 100 composers that each had the layers locked. It also explained why he was the only one who was constantly complaining about his laptop being too slow for the work :)

Answer (score -1):

in answer to your statement “My question concerns the general purpose of the composer in qgis”
For me and as In understand the purpose of  the print composer in qgis is more to provide an output for GIS project in a cartographic format .and it is very Cleary detailed in the qgis documentation   “The Print Composer provides growing layout and printing capabilities. It allows you to add elements such as the QGIS map canvas, text labels, images, legends, scale bars, basic shapes, arrows, attribute tables and HTML frames “(see the link bellow)

If you need more information about how to use it please visit this link 
https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html?highlight=qgis%20composer

Best Regard,